# Check if NSDocument is new

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, document-based

How do you know if a `NSDocument` is new?

I'm currently using `fileURL != nil` but I couldn't find any place in the documentation that confirms this.

Also, `fileURL` returns `nil` in restored documents (after quitting the app without saving and then opening the app again). Is it possible to differentiate between a new document and a restored document?

Comment: If it's new I need to show a different window. If it's restored I need to disable certain features.

Comment: By "restored", do you mean the user viewing it in the Versions browser? Or actually after that, when a document has been restored from the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial-and-error:

```
- (BOOL) readFromURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
    self.isNew = NO; // New documents don't call this method

    BOOL success = [super readFromURL:url ofType:typeName error:outError];

    // This must go after calling super
    self.isSaved = self.fileURL != nil; // Saved documents set fileURL
    self.isUnsaved = self.fileURL == nil; // Unsaved/restored documents don't set fileURL. The url parameter points to a temporary folder.

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `-[NSDocument draft]`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocument/1515065-draft